# Thymeleaf + Spring >>> copy checked values from HTML table

Tags: spring, list, checkbox, binding

I'm new to Spring and Thymeleaf and I'm stuck.
What I try ist to copy checked values from one HTML table to another (later on the values will be passed to be stored in MySQL table.

I tried different approaches but nothing works and I get exasperated with this problem. I really hope you can help me:

This works: (it's not what's required though)

```html
<tr th:id="${cList.zoneId}" th:each="cList, rowStat: ${countryZoneList}" class="clickable-row">
  <td><input th:for="${cList.zoneId}" type="checkbox" th:name="zones" th:value="${cList.zoneId}" /></td>
  <td th:text="${cList.zoneSymbol}"></td>
  <td th:text="${cList.zoneName}"></td>
  <td class="hiddenColumn" th:id="${cList.zoneId}"></td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/confirmCountries", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String confirmCountriesPost(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            @ModelAttribute("zones") String zones,
            Model model, Principal principal
            ) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("zones: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + zones);

        return "my-dashboard";

    }
```

Here I get the expected printout: 3 (value from the first zoneId)
I don't need the other values. I indeed need only the integer values, meaning the values of the 'selected' checkboxes.

What doesn't work:

```html
<tr th:id="${cList.zoneId}" th:each="cList, rowStat: ${countryZoneList}" class="clickable-row">
    <td><input th:for="${cList.zoneId}" type="checkbox" th:name="zones" th:value="${cList.zoneId}"/></td>
    <td th:text="${cList.zoneSymbol}"></td>
    <td th:text="${cList.zoneName}"></td>
    <td class="hiddenColumn" th:id="${cList.zoneId}"></td>
</tr>
```

Neither works this:

```html
    <tr th:id="${cList.zoneId}" th:each="cList, rowStat: ${countryZoneList}" class="clickable-row">
<td><input th:for="${cList.zoneId}" type="checkbox" th:field="*{zones}" th:value="${cList.zoneId}"/></td>
<td th:text="${cList.zoneSymbol}"></td>
<td th:text="${cList.zoneName}"></td>
<td class="hiddenColumn" th:id="${cList.zoneId}"></td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/confirmCountries", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String confirmCountriesPost(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        @ModelAttribute("zones") ArrayList<String> zones,
        Model model, Principal principal
        ) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("zones: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + zones.size());

    return "my-dashboard";

}
```

So here I try to store multiple values (the whole list) of selected values from the form to this ArrayList. The problem is, that even, when I check multiple checboxes ny ArrayList shows always the size of 1 (it stores only the first value). Where is the problem? Please help. How do I get the whole list of my 'cList.zoneI' values? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none posted an answer, but I found finally the solution.

**Snippet of Thymeleaf:**

```html
    <form id="left-table" class="form-countries-confirm" th:object="${CountryZoneTable}" th:action="@{/deleteSelectedZones}" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="proofheaderId" th:value="${proofheaderID}" />
<input type="hidden" name="company" th:value="${company}" />
<input type="hidden" name="datumVon" th:value="${datumVon}" />
<input type="hidden" name="datumBis" th:value="${datumBis}" />
<div class="col-md-5">
<!-- Ausgabe der Daten - Tabelle -->
<table id="unCountriesData" class="table table-striped display hover">
<thead> 
<tr>                    <th>Ländercode/ Zone</th>                   <th>Land</th>                    <th data-orderable="false"><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkBoxes(this)"></input></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<!-- Loop für die Daten -->
<tr th:id="${uList.zoneId}" th:each="uList : ${unCountriesList}" class="clickable-row">
<td th:text="${uList.zoneSymbol}"></td>
<td th:text="${uList.zoneName}"></td>
<td>                     <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{newZoneList}" th:value="${uList.zoneId}" id="zone" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script th:inline="javascript" type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
$(document).ready(function() {                      $('#unCountriesData').DataTable();
} );
/*]]>*/  
</script>
<!-- Ende Tabelle -->
</div>
<input type="submit" id="delete-zones" class="hidden" /> 
</form>
```

**And the necessary controller response:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/confirmCountries", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String confirmCountries(Model model, Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request,
        @ModelAttribute("company") String company,
        @ModelAttribute("datumVon") String datumVon,
        @ModelAttribute("datumBis") String datumBis,
        @ModelAttribute("CountryZoneTable") SelectedZones zoneList,
        @ModelAttribute("CountryZoneTable") SelectedZones newZoneList
        ) throws Exception {


long proofheaderId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("proofheaderId"));

    if((Long) proofheaderId == null) {

        model.addAttribute("classActiveOverview", true);

        return "my-dashboard";
    }



// Der Benutzer wird nach dem Benutzernamen gesucht und als 'user' als Attribtu an HTML übergeben
        String username = principal.getName();
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);

        // Die Liste aller Zonen (alle Felder) wird extrahiert und als Attribut an HTML übergeben
        List<CountryZone> countryZoneList = countryZoneService.findByZoneId();
        model.addAttribute("countryZoneList", countryZoneList);

        // Die Arbeitgruppe, der der Benutzer angehört wird herausgesucht
        Usergroup usergroup = usergroupService.findByUsergroupId(user.getUserGroup());

        // Liste der ausgewählten Zonen aus den 'UNCountries' wird anhand von ID des Nachweises herausgesucht
        List<UNCountries> unCountriesList = unCountriesService.findByProofheaderId(proofheaderId);

        // Es wird ein String aus ausgesuchten Zonen-Namen und dazugehörigen Symbolen ausgesucht
        String unCountriesAsString = unCountriesService.stringOfCountries(proofheaderId);

    int iProgress = proofheaderService.getProgressValue(proofheaderId);

    // Liste wird als Attribut an HTML übergeben
    model.addAttribute("unCountriesList", unCountriesList);

    // String mit den Ländern für TextArea
    model.addAttribute("unCountriesAsString", unCountriesAsString);


    /*///// Diese Liste enthält die ProofheaderDateien die in der Tabelle angezeigt werden /////*/
    List<Proofheader> phList = proofheaderService.findByUsergroup(user.getUserGroup());
    model.addAttribute("proofheaderList", phList);


    model.addAttribute("usergroup", usergroup);
    model.addAttribute("classActiveCountriesConfirm", true);
    model.addAttribute("proofheaderID", proofheaderId);
    model.addAttribute("company", company);
    model.addAttribute("datumVon", datumVon);
    model.addAttribute("datumBis", datumBis);

    model.addAttribute("progress", iProgress);

    return "my-dashboard";

}
```

**And a helper class I created for the lists of checbox values:**

```
 import java.util.List;

public class SelectedZones {

    // Variable für alle Zonen aus der CountryZone Tabelle
    private List<Long> zoneList;

    // die ausgesuchten Werte, die in in die UNCountries Tabelle abgelegt werden
    private List<Long> newZoneList;

    public List<Long> getZoneList() {
        return zoneList;
    }

    public void setZoneList(List<Long> zoneList) {
        this.zoneList = zoneList;
    }

    public List<Long> getNewZoneList() {
        return newZoneList;
    }

    public void setNewZoneList(List<Long> newZoneList) {
        this.newZoneList = newZoneList;
    }

}
```

**The most important part of this:**
Take a look at this HTML/ Thymeleaf

```
    <tbody>
   <tr th:id="${cList.zoneId}" th:each="cList : ${countryZoneList}" class="clickable-row">
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{zoneList}" th:value="${cList.zoneId}" id="zone" />  
</td>
<td th:text="${cList.zoneSymbol}"></td>
<td th:text="${cList.zoneName}"></td>
<td class="hiddenColumn" th:id="${cList.zoneId}"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

As you can see the chec box field is named as follow:

```html
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{zoneList}" th:value="${cList.zoneId}" id="zone" />
```

It's exactly the same name as you request in your controller class and the same name as the variable name in your helper class.